# Pass two objects from controller to view without using a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller method that I want to use to send to a view a list and a decimal, without using models. How can I do so?
Here is my call to the view from the controller :

```
decimal totBalance = 10.0M;
return View(query.ToList(), totBalance);
```

Comment: Use `ViewBag` for `totBalance`

Comment: *without using models*, why? A model is the correct solution here. **M**VC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.ViewBag**

Pass your `list` item as `Model` and total balance in `ViewBage`.

```
  public ActionResult ActionName()
        {
            var list= query.ToList();
           decimal totBalance = 10.0M;   
           ViewBag.Banance= totBalance ;          
            return View(list);
        }
```

Use:

```
 @{
    var list= Model;
    var totBalance=ViewBag.Banance ;
  }
```

**2.ExpandoObject**

Pass dynamic object as `Model`.

```
public ExpandoObject ToExpando( object anonymousObject)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> anonymousDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(anonymousObject);
        IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (var item in anonymousDictionary)
            expando.Add(item);
        return (ExpandoObject)expando;
    }


 public ActionResult ActionName()
    {
        var list= query.ToList();
       decimal totBalance = 10.0M;
          var model= ToExpando(new{ ListValue=list,Balance  =totBalance})
        return View(model);
    }
```

Use:

```
@{//don't need use @model List<ModelName> or something like as model
var list= Model.ListValue;
var totBalance=Model.Balance  ;
}
```

Comment: Neat, I like your anonymousObject approach.  I hadn't thought of doing that, but it's a nice quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct, this really should be a model. Your best bet would be to create a model such as:

```
public SomeModel
{
    List<DatabaseEntity> Entity { get; set; }
    decimal TotBalance { get;set; }
}
```

This would allow you to instantiate that in the controller and populate it with the query.ToList() and totBalance variables.

Then you can return it as the view model and map your model properties easily.

---

If you cannot (for some reason) use a model class, the ViewBag approach mentioned in by @MahediSabuj is an ugly solution but would work. You can pass one or both of your variables to the ViewBag from the controller.

(Controller):`ViewBag.TotBalance = totBalance;`

(View) -- just an example:`<p> @ViewBag.TotBalance </p>`

One concern is that the ViewBag stores values as obj and will need to be properly cast if they are required for any calculations, etc:

`@if ( (decimal)ViewBag.TotBalance > 10.50) { ... }`